# MySQL BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER is not affecting first record entry

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to calculate the differential column of the score table upon inserting into a MySQL 8.0 database using a before trigger. The calculation uses the coursetee table as well. The trigger works fine on all but the first record in the table, which doesn't get updated. Is there something that I am missing? All relevant code is below.

```
CREATE TABLE coursetee (
    teeID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    tee_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    course_rating DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL, 
    slope_rating INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    par INT UNSIGNED,
    CONSTRAINT pk_coursetee PRIMARY KEY (teeID),   

CREATE TABLE score (
    roundID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    teeID INT UNSIGNED, 
    round_score INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    round_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    entry_date DATETIME DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
    differential DECIMAL(3,1),  
    CONSTRAINT pk_score PRIMARY KEY (roundID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_score_coursetee FOREIGN KEY (teeID) REFERENCES coursetee(teeID));    

DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER calculate_differential
    BEFORE INSERT ON score
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.differential = (SELECT ROUND((113/ct.slope_rating)*(NEW.round_score-ct.course_rating),1) 
            FROM score, coursetee as ct
            WHERE NEW.teeID = ct.teeID AND differential IS NULL);
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO coursetee 
    (courseID,tee_name,course_rating,slope_rating,par)
    VALUES
    (1,'Back',74.7,143,72),
    (1,'Middle',72.6,136,72),
    (1,'Front',71.3,132,72),
    (2,'Back',76.8,155,72),
    (2,'Middle',73.9,146,72),
    (2,'Front',65.3,125,72);    

INSERT INTO score
    (playerID,teeID,round_score,round_date)
    VALUES
    (1,2,79,'2019-07-25');

INSERT INTO score
    (playerID,teeID,round_score,round_date)
    VALUES
    (2,2,80,'2019-07-25');

INSERT INTO score
    (playerID,teeID,round_score,round_date)
    VALUES
    (1,2,77,'2019-08-06');
```

The query returns:
[image of query not returning calculated record for row 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iybZm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER calculate_differential
BEFORE INSERT 
ON score
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.differential = ( SELECT ROUND((113/ct.slope_rating)*(NEW.round_score-ct.course_rating),1) 
                         FROM coursetee ct
                         WHERE NEW.teeID = ct.teeID);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=950259fc0625ce1445ccd5c67feb8c07)

The problem was in using `score` table as a source of the subquery. And the hope that `differential` BEFORE inserting the first record will give anything except NOT FOUND. And testing the field of the record BEFORE INSERT for NULL makes no sense.

Comment: Works perfectly! I didn't like checking for NULL, but it gave me an error after the second insert if I didn't check for the new value being NULL. This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score -1):

My assumption is about the FROM clause of the differential query in the trigger. i'd suggest you to try change the order of the tables -

```
FROM score, coursetee as ct
```

to

```
FROM coursetee as ct, score
```

Seems like its trying to extract nothing for the first insert...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but didn't work, still same result.